# How does Google Finance calculate the Institution Owned metric for a stock

Tags: mutual-funds, google-finance

How does Google Finance calculate the Inst. Owned metric on the stock page. For example, this stock page for [Jet Blue](https://www.google.ca/finance?q=NASDAQ%3aJBLU&ei=buglU6CJMcSMqgGOXQ)

says:
Inst Owned: 100%, but does that seem feasible. It means that all of the stock is in the hands of pension funds, mutual funds and hedge funds and none at all is controlled by the retail investor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Institutional ownership has nearly lost all meaning.

It used to mean mutual funds, investment banks, etc.

Now, it means pension funds, who hold the rest of the equity assets directly, and insiders.

Since the vast majority of investors in equity do not hold it directly, "institutions" are approaching 100% ownership on all major equities.

Other sites still [segment the data](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/mh?s=JBLU%20Major%20Holders).

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate :' majority of investors in equity do not hold it directly'? You mean they hold it through an ETF/mutual fund etc?

Comment: @Victor123 Right, but pensions are a massive part of the market too.  All in, it's about a 2:1 ratio of indirect to direct, discounting unlisted securities.